# Read tabbed files in python

Tags: python, file-io

I have integer data as follows in a .txt file.

```
600  17  3488541
601  21  6523232
602  18  6565444
603  23  6655656
```

It goes on like that. The file is pretty huge. In a specific program I need to get each of the values in a line into an integer variable and use it and then the values in the next line and so on.

I have gone through a lots of tutorials but nothing explains how to do my purpose.

To be specific, here is what I need exactly. I have three variables, say `a`, `b` and `c`.
All these 3 variables are initialized in a `while`-loop. In the first execution of the while loop the values must be:

```
a=600
b=17
c=3488541
```

In the second execution it has to be:

```
a=601
b=21
c=6523232
```

...and so on. How can I do it? I am a beginner in Python. The working platform is Linux.

Comment: What did you try?  The documentation on http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html gives several concrete examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      a, b, c = map(int, line.split())
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

A file with tab-separated values is just a dialect of the classic [comma-separated values (CSV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file where the delimiter is a tab (`\t`).

Happily, Python comes with a [**`csv.reader`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) `class` that understands [dialect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect)s.

You should use this (and give your values more appropriate names than `a, b, c`).

### Example:

```
% cat ./integers.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
csv.register_dialect('tsv', delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
with open('integers.txt', 'r') as integers:
    reader = csv.reader(integers, 'tsv')
    for row in reader:
        paper, student, score = (int(column) for column in row)
        print paper, student, score
```

Running:

```
% ./integers.py   
600 17 3488541
601 21 6523232
602 18 6565444
603 23 6655656
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("filename.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        a, b, c = map(int, line.split())
        # do something with a, b, c here
```

However, you might find it easier to just leave the items in a list. For example, if you are adding them up or something, it's easier to do `sum(list)` rather than `a + b + c`, and scales better if you ever need it for files with more than three fields.  For this sort of thing, just do:

```
with open("filename.txt") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        numbers = map(int, line.split())
        print sum(numbers)   # or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution.

```
lines = open('data.txt').read().splitlines()
lines = [map(int, i.split()) for i in lines]
for a,b,c in lines:
    print a,b,c
```

Comment: I would convert the `lines` from a list to a generator as the OP stated that the file was very large.

Comment: I agree, I think as for performance @kindall's answers works better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the csv module:

```
import csv
fcont = csv.reader(open("file_path"), delimiter="\t") #tab separated
for (row, (a, b, c)) in enumerate(fcont): #a b c are strings. you can map(int, (a, b, c))
    do_something(a, b, c)
```

without csv module:

```
f = open("file_path")
fcont = f.read().splitlines(); f.close()
for (row, rcont) in fcont:
    (a, b, c) = rcont.split("\t") #tab separated #you can map(int, (a, b, c))
    do_something(a, b, c)
```